# ggsave cannot export a readable plot even with a dpi of 3000

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggsave

Using the code below, I am trying to save a ggplot to as a png file. Although dpi is pretty high, the saved png file is not even readable. As shown in the image below, the export option in the files pane provides a better resolution. Is there any way to fix this?

```
ggsave(file="circulatory_1999_2018_55+_new.png", path = "~/Desktop/cause of death/Data Slice", width = 1200, height = 500, units = "mm", dpi=3000)
```

[image: saved with export option]

Comment: those widths and heights are really high, i usually pick numbers closer to 10. try modifying them?

Comment: Nice monitors have DPI around 200. That would mean your 1.2 meter by 0.5 meter plot at 3000 dpi would need a 20m x 7.5m monitor to view all the pixels at once (3000 / 200 = 15 scaling factor). My guess is that your image viewer is overwhelmed by the gigantic image and is doing a poor job downscaling to fit it on your monitor. Try scaling back, change the height/width to something reasonable like 180 x 75 mm and the `dpi` to 300 - I bet it will look a lot better.

Comment: Thanks. What unit of measurement is used in the export option in the files pane? Width=1180 and Height=475?

Comment: Try  `width = 7, height = 5, dpi = 100, units = "in"`

Comment: @NaderMehri that is in pixels. Your image is 120x larger in width and height than that.

Comment: A quick search suggests that glossy magazines use about 150 dpi, and nice fine art prints use 240 dpi. If you go over 300 (for print), you're not going to see a difference without a magnifying class.